# Autotools and cross building

Tags: bash, mingw, autotools, configure

I'm currently patching a project which should build and run both in linux systems and in windows, using mingw into msys1.
The master development branch offers a 'raw' source code tree, namely, it needs autotools in order to configure and build.

Now, I have to say I know very little of autotools and I'm actually reading the docs I found floating around, but an answer is still missing: when running autotools in linux or in windows environment, are they expected to generate the same scripts?
In my experience, the generated scripts differ and under different OSs the configure scripts go to run or fail (I mean, it is not configure failing at checking for a library, it gets interrupted because of a real script error).

What is their expected right behaviour?

Comment: yeah a few scripts are generated according to automake, autoheader, m4, libtool, etc. Those are shell portable. MSYS[1/2] will execute them fine.

Comment: @Joel did you **really** read my question ?

Comment: Did you **really** read my answer? The scripts are generated ACCORDING to automake, autoheader, bla bla, meaning as logic it is, depends the versions between your OSs that generate those scripts making portable to your MSYS or whatever.